# How to put siunitx units in a parenthesis or an equation?

Tags: siunitx

I want to put units in an equation. Someone published a paper with units written that way. I need to mimic that. A simple case would be:

```
\begin{equation}
   a = \si{\ell}{(\cm)}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
   a = \si{\ell}{\cm}
\end{equation}
```

But both give Undefined control sequence. I think the problem is that I do not know how to use the package siunitx in an equation.

Comment: The `\si` command takes only one argument, which is the unit to print. If you want to print a number as well use `\SI`. To print non-numeric numbers (?) use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\ell}{\cm}`. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Did you load `siunitx`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Your solution worked. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\si` command takes only one argument, which is the unit to print. If you want to print a number as well use `\SI{<number>}{<unit>}`.

However, `siunitx` tries to parse the `<number>`, and when you give it `\ell` it tells you:

```
! Package siunitx Error: Invalid token '\ell ' in numerical input.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.5   a = \SI{\ell}{\cm}

? h

Numbers can only contain tokens defined using the 'input-...' options:
the token '\ell ' is not set up as a valid part of a number.
```

To have `siunitx` print a non-numerical input you can disable the parsing mechanism with `parse-numbers=false`:

```
\begin{equation}
  a = \SI[parse-numbers=false]{\ell}{\cm}
\end{equation}
```

or, if you're going to use it several times in the same equation:

```
\begin{equation}
  \sisetup{parse-numbers=false}
  a = \SI{\ell}{\cm}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: It turned out that a simpler solution in the equation environment is `\ell \si{(\cm)}`

Comment: @wander95 Note that the spacing is different, though. Try `a = \ell\,\si{\cm}`.